# How are cross-window function invocations implemented in different browers?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I have a parent window and a child window that was opened by the parent window by `var child = window.open('');`. There is supposed to be inter-window communication in my usecase. So that the parent window calls functions in the child window. The problem is in how slow it happens. Hence my question: **What is the cross-window function invocation mechanism in IE, Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari?**

UPDATE:

I have a strong suspicion that the calls from the parent to a child window are translated to messages that are posted to the message loop of a child window keeping the parent window blocked. Can anyone confirm \ disprove this?

Comment: i can recommend you easyXDM